# Why is the internal folder (context.filesDir) cleared when updating the app?

Tags: android, migration

I want to update an app (from version 2 to 3). 
I am using Room as DB engine, I do have some migration scripts, they are executed OK.
But I notice that the my files which I created in version 2 & saved in private folder (context.filesDir), are not present after update to version 3. This happens on 1 device, on another it works.

I perform the check in first line in Application class - so prior to any code being executed (migration or other code)
I've also placed a breakPoint on File.delete -> NOT called at all

According to debugger my internal folder is:
`/data/user/0/<packageName>/files`

Since DB migration works, DB file was found..

I just don't get it.. What can be the cause? The internal file is fixed & should be kept when updating app..

Test devices:

Nexus 5x (Android 8.1) - files are missing (not OK)

Samsung M20 (Android 8.1), Sony Xperia XZ (Android 7.1.1) - files are found (OK)

Comment: "Why is the internal folder (context.filesDir) cleared when updating the app?" -- it is not. How are you looking for the files? How are you determining that they have been deleted? "According to debugger my internal folder is: /data/user/0//files" -- there will be an application ID where you have the empty path segment.

Comment: Fixed.. stackOverflow applied some formatting 

In app version 2:
- I save the files directly in context.filesDir
/data/user/0/<packageName>/files/<fileName>
- I also save path in DB (file.absolutePath)

After UPDATE to version 3, context.filesDir is empty.
First check, in Application class, I just print content of filesDir
Log.d("##", " FILES: ${this.filesDir.list().joinToString()}") //Empty

Then whey I try read the File (by the path save in DB) I get FileNotFound..

Comment: Databases are not stored in `context.filesDir`, at least not by default. They are stored in an adjacent directory.

Comment: Yes, private/internal folder is: /data/user/0/<packageName>/files
While, DB is in /data/user/0/<packageName>/databases
Db migration works.. so DB file is found
Weirdly this proved to work OK on 2 devices, only on Nexus 5x it clears my files..

Comment: My point is that looking in `context.filesDir` to see if your database was deleted will not work. At this point, I recommend that you provide a [mcve] showing your `RoomDatabase` and `Migration` code along with the complete stack trace associated with your crash.